# Facebook og:image property issue

Tags: facebook, header, head

Facebook sharing debugger is giving me the following issues for a [website](http://www.kink.cz/najforever/index.html) i'm doing right now:

> The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
> The 'og:url' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
> The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
> The 'og:description' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

Facebook sharing **scraper** is giving website description and title from instagram, which it is probably scraping from the script that runs on the page. Could you please suggest what could be the problem? Here is  content:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="Máme rádi léto i zimu, dobrodružství i oddych - hlavně ať je nám super. Jsme vlogeři, který si užívají krásní momenty do posledního okamžiku. Prostě #Najforever">
<meta NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="INDEX, FOLLOW">
<meta name="keywords" content="najforever" />
<title>#Najforever</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fxsmall.css" />
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="image_src" href="http://www.najforever.cz/img/fbpreview1.jpg" / >
<link rel="image_src" href="http://www.najforever.cz/img/fbpreview2.jpg" / >
<link rel="image_src" href="http://www.najforever.cz/img/fbpreview3.jpg" / >
<meta content="http://www.najforever.cz" property="og:url" />
<meta content="#NAJFOREVER" property="og:title" />
<meta content="#NAJFOREVER je skupina přátel a současně digitální agentura spojující a zastupující přední módní a lifestylové blogery česko-slovenské scény." property="og:description" />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--This is a script to change opacity of img.-->
```

Thank you

Comment: Because you specify http://www.najforever.cz as og:url. So we will fetch tags from that one. But that one redirects to Instagram so we will fetch tags from there

Comment: Oh yes, you're right :) thank you very much. Will that show the link images as well, or do I have to use og meta as well for that?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean